# JSON sended by cURL has errors with utf8mb4 data

Tags: php, json, api, curl, encode

> I've a script in PHP that reads from a table in DDBB, set a JSON and
>   send it by cURL but the endpoint receive characters like accents wrong
>   (*acutes*).

**1) Firstly, i connect to the bbdd and set the charset:**

```
$conn=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8mb4");
```

The database collation is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, **I can't change that**.

**2) I build the array with the info:**

```
$arr_json = array();
$array_json['key'] = htmlentities("Más");
[...]
```

**3) Once is settled, create the JSON from the array:**

```
$arr_json = json_encode($arr_json,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

**4) Finally, i send the info:**

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => URL,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $arr_json,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/json",
      ),
    ));
```

I receive a *200* code, but the endoint of the API always receive wrong input, for example a previous value of:

```
'Más'
```

It would be:

```
'M&aacute;s'
```

The PHP script file is UTF-8, and the info in database is correctly stored. Any ideas?

Comment: @SahilGulati how it could be? charset in CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON and CURL have nothing to do with this, you're explicitly escaping the characters here:

```
$array_json['key'] = htmlentities("Más");
```

That turns `"Más"` into `'M&aacute;s'`.